# how to send post data with inappbrowser ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, inappbrowser

I need to know how you can send data by post via `inappbrowser` to an external *url* that is a payment gateway

I am dealing with the property of `ionic` execute Script however I have not managed to pass the post data, I would like to see if there is another way but I need to use `inappbrowser`

```
 let options: InAppBrowserOptions={
      zoom:'no',clearcache:'yes',hidden:'yes',hidenavigationbuttons:'yes',hideurlbar:'yes'
    };
    let customheader= 'foo:123,bar:456';
    const browser= this.iab.create('https://url_anyway','_blank',options);
    browser.on('loadstop').subscribe( (ev: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
      browser.executeScript({code: "(function() {const data = new FormData(document.getElementById('mp_account'));fetch('https://url_anyway', {   method: 'POST',   body: data}).then(function(response) {   if(response.ok) {       return response.text()   } else {       throw 'Error en la llamada Ajax';}}).then(function(texto) {   console.log(texto);}).catch(function(err) {   console.log(err);});  })()"}).then( function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          browser.show();
        ;}, 1500);

      }); 
    });
```

when opening the url does not show anything by post method